# My function does not return what it should

Tags: c, function

I have an issue with a function I've created. It doesn't return `1`. I tried using the code in `main` instead of in the function and it worked.

I don't know if I'm missing something or what so please check it out and tell me:

```
int happynum(int n); // THIS IS THE FUNCTION

int main()
{
int num,digito,i,dig,temp,sum=0, lol;

do {
printf("Escribe un numero positivo:\n");
scanf("%d", &num);
} while (num <= 0);

    lol = happynum(num); // THIS IS WHAT THE FUNCTION RETURN
    printf("%d ", lol);

    while(num!=89 && num!=1)   //THIS IS THE SAME FUNCTION BUT IN THE MAIN
{
   sum=0;
   while(num>0)
  {
    dig=num%10;
    num=num/10;
    sum=sum+(dig*dig);
  }
  num=sum;
}

printf("%d", num);
/*
if(num== 1)
{
     printf("Happy Number\n");
}
 else
 printf("UnHappy Number\n"); */
    return 0;
}
```

This is the function:

```
int happynum(int n)  // THIS IS THE FUNCTION
{
int i,dig,num,sum=0;

while(num!=89 && num!=1)
{
   sum=0;
   while(num>0)
  {
    dig=num%10;
    num=num/10;
    sum=sum+(dig*dig);
  }
  num=sum;
}
  return num;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to declare the function as `happynum( int num )` and omit the declaration of `num` on the following line? Looks like you aren't doing anything with parameter `n`

Comment: Please don't shout. Don't use all capital letters in title.

Comment: @BobKaufman thanks, I did that but the console is left with the number entered and does not follow next instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `num` local to `happynum` instead of the parameter that you pass. Name the argument `num` and then use that, like so:

```
int happynum(int num)  // THIS IS THE FUNCTION
{
int i,dig,sum=0;

while(num!=89 && num!=1)
{
   sum=0;
   while(num>0)
  {
    dig=num%10;
    num=num/10;
    sum=sum+(dig*dig);
  }
  num=sum;
}
  return num;
}
```

You should then probably un-comment the block at the end of your `main` so you get the `Un`/`Happy Number` result.